# Занести в БД значения из списка, которых в этой базе еще нет

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся с такой задачей. Имеется список из данных, который программа получает извне. Необходимо занести в таблицу базы PostgreSQL элементы из этого списка, которых еще нет в таблице. Моя реализация выглядит так (Используется SQLAlchemy):

Считать данные из базы во множество

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql://*******:******@localhost:5432/******", future=True)
engine.connect()

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)

unit_table = Table('unit', metadata, autoload=True)

# Считывание
stmt = select(unit_table.c.name)
units = set()
for el in conn.execute(stmt).fetchall():
    units.add(el[0])
```

Найти уникальные элементы из полученного множества, и текущего списка преобразованного во множество(во избежание дублирования элементов)

```
new_units = ["М", "Км/Ч", "М/С"]
unique_units = set(new_units) - units
```

И далее заношу эти элементы в таблицу бд

```
conn.execute(insert(unit_table),[{"name": value} for value in (unique_units)],)
conn.commit()
```

В моем способе мне не нравится то, что данные сначала считываются, потом преобразуются, и только потом после этого добавляются уникальные элементы. Считаю этот процесс не оптимальным не по времени не по памяти, особенно на большом количестве данных.

Как оптимизировать данный процесс? Возможно ли реализовать процесс добавления отсутствующих данных в таблицу базы, из набора, которые присутствуют в этом наборе, но отсутствуют в таблице **без считывания данных из базы?**

*Python 3.11.1, SQLAlchemy 1.4.43, PostgreSQL 15.3.1*

Comment: Сделайте на таблице уникальный ключ и записывайте в лоб(с обработкой исключения дубликата индекса). Так вы себе будете гарантировать, что в таблице только уникальные значения. Еще можно сделать что то вида(я условно) вьюшки или динамического запроса: сначала делаем селект записей из таблицы так - `select values, b.name from dual a left join myTable b on a.values = b.name where b.name is null` - и вы получите выборку тех зачений, которых нет в вашей таблице

Comment: @SwaD, спасибо за комментарий, попробую поработать в этом направлении

Comment: В стандарте SQL есть команда MERGE. Ей указывается целевая таблица, набор данных, и что делать если записи нет (например, INSERT) и если запись есть (например, UPDATE)

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, спасибо, почитаю про MERGE

Comment: Ну или INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING.